# Why does accessing a class property in this TypeScript example throw error TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'T'?

Tags: typescript, narrowing

Can someone please explain why accessing a class property in this example is throwing `error TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'T'.`

Code (TypeScript):

```js
class Base {
    readonly name: string = this.constructor.name;
};

class MyClass extends Base {
    text: string;

    constructor(v: string) {
        super();
        this.text = v;
    }
};

function CreateMyClass<T>(type: new (v: string) => T) {
    console.debug('CreateMyClass: type:', type)

    const myClass: T = new type('hello world');

    console.debug('CreateMyClass: myClass:', myClass);
    // console.debug('CreateMyClass: myClass.text:', myClass.text);
}

CreateMyClass(MyClass);
```

Output (as above):

```
CreateMyClass: type: [class MyClass extends Base]
CreateMyClass: myClass: MyClass { name: 'MyClass', text: 'hello world' }
```

Output (uncommented last console.debug statement):

```
test/index.ts:20:59 - error TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'T'.

20     console.debug('CreateMyClass: myClass.text:', myClass.text);
                                                             ~~~~
```

Comment: Why would it work? Consider the call `CreateMyClass<Base>(Base)` - the instance that was created wouldn't have a `text` property.

Comment: Why _would_ it have that property? Without any generic constraint you give the compiler no information about what you expect the type to be. Why use a generic type at all?

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using NodeJS with TypeScript. The outputs are run with ts-node in zsh on macOS.

Comment: You can [edit] the question, but that's really not relevant.

Comment: @VLAZ & @jonrsharpe : But the `text` property, and it's value from the constructor, is set and logs in the first console.debug. I have been using TypeScript for a little while, but I am still learning. Just trying to understand.

Comment: I don't see why that would matter. The result is irrelevant of the OS or what you use to launch your application. It just doesn't make sense at the type level. Nothing to do with OS or your shell.

Comment: "*But the text property, and it's value from the constructor, is set and logs in the first console.debug.*" Yes, because you're logging the whole instance *whatever it is*. You're not logging the TS type which *doesn't exist at runtime*. The type system only exists at compiletime. And there is no information at that point whether or not `T` would contain `text`. And it very definitely might not - see my example in the first comment.

Comment: "Yes, because you're logging the whole instance whatever it is. You're not logging the TS type which doesn't exist at runtime."
Ok, that makes a little more sense, but is there a way to mutate the `text` property before the return?

Comment: Either define that `T` *must* include `text` or...try to hack around it. At which point the question is why even use TS or generics if you'd be ignoring that, though. This may very well be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what is the point of introducing a generic function that will call a constructor if seems to *only* care about a specific constructor? You may not need a generic there. Of if you do - then you need to constrain it.

Comment: This example is a representation of another scenario - I didn't want to introduce the real purpose behind my question until an understanding of the error in it's simplest form was understood. I understand why I am getting that error now.

The actual problem I am trying to solve is this:
I have an array of classes where all elements derive from the same base class and only one instance of each class is allowed. I would like another method to retrieve an element of type, like getElement<T>() { return <the only element of type T in the array>; }

Comment: I don't actually see what the question (Y) has to do with your real problem (X). But again, the types are not available at runtime. Thus a function like `getElement<MyClass>()` cannot work because there is no way to examine what the generic argument was at runtime. There needs to be something concrete for the code to use.

Answer (score 0):

Both @VLAZ and @jonrsharpe answered my original question. And @VLAZ was correct that my question is an "XY Problem".

**ANSWER:**
"...You're not logging the TS type which doesn't exist at runtime. The type system only exists at compiletime. And there is no information at that point whether or not T would contain text. And it very definitely might not - see my example in the first comment." – @VLAZ

And, the solution to my underlying question, "Can I mutate a property instantiated by the function `CreateMyClass`?" - No

I did mention that I am seeking a solution to another problem:

How to retrieve an element of type T (where T inherits from `BaseClass`) in an array of `BaseClass` using a function that takes in the derived class. Consider the following code:

```js
class Base {
    readonly name: string = this.constructor.name;
};

class MyClass extends Base {
    text: string;

    constructor(v: string) {
        super();
        this.text = v;
    }
};

class MyContainer {
    arr: Base[] = [];

    getChild<T>(childType: new (s: string) => T): T {
        for (const child of this.arr) {
            if (child instanceof childType) {
                return child;
            }
        }

        return undefined;
    }
}

const myContainer: MyContainer = new MyContainer();
myContainer.arr.push(new MyClass('some text'));

console.debug(myContainer.getChild(MyClass));
```

console.debug output:
`MyClass { text: "some text" }`

So, ultimately, I did eventually find a solution to the underlying issue. Hopefully it helps others coming up through learning TypeScript.

Thank you to @VLAZ and @jonrsharpe for your help.